# CMake cannot buid GLFW library - problems in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

*CMake noob arrived.*

I've downloaded the GLFW source code and tried to build it. So, problems are inevitable.

CMake error:

```
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library glfw without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
```

Problem code in CMakeLists.txt (this file is too large for completely copy-paste, but I can post it if you require):

```
set_target_properties(glfw PROPERTIES
                      OUTPUT_NAME ${GLFW_LIB_NAME}
                      VERSION ${GLFW_VERSION}
                      SOVERSION ${GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR}
                      POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
                      FOLDER "GLFW3")
```

Common surface Googling and attempts to replace the file were ineffectually.

CMake version: **3.8.0-rc1**

---

*P.S. Sorry for my English.*

Comment: What is your CMake version? No problems here with 3.7.2.

Comment: CMake version 3.8.0

Comment: Looks like you have **broken sources**. Actually, the warning about "ADD_LIBRARY without source files" looks suspicios. The library is created in [src/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt), and **non-empty source list** for the library is selected according to underline platform (`_GLFW_*` variables). And one of these variables is **definitely set** set in main [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L162): if no suitable platform is detected, fatal error is raised.

Comment: OP may have specified the `src` subdirectory as source directory to CMake.

Comment: @elmindreda: You seems to be right. Message `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56` refers to the file in the top-level source directory. @СлаваС: You need to use `glwf` instead of `glfw/src` as source directory when run `cmake`.